# How to chose the best audio device

Tags: audio, drivers, motherboard

I recently built an Intel 6th Gen PC with the Asus z170 Pro Gaming as the mother board! Well the PC is running fine and I am using an original copy of windows 10. I have an Asus Xonar DGX 5.1 Audio card and they didn't have drivers for that device up until now. The motherboard contains a Supreme FX sound card and I have a 5.1 system hooked upto it. Will it degrade the sound quality if I plug the PCI-e DGX card and use it rather than the onboard sound chip. Since they say that the onboard card is also a pretty good device what is the best option?

Please forgive me if this sort of a question is not suitable on this forum. Guide me.

Please help me!

Comment: while one sound card might have better technical specs than the other, that doesnt mean it has better audio quality.  The answer is purely a matter of one's own opinion.  The best thing you can do is try them both and make your own decision as to which you think is better.  Unless you have super high quality audio recording and playback needs, you probably wont hear much of a difference between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can connect your mainboard and your 5.1 system digitally via spdif or hdmi, I would recommend to leave the extra sound card out. That way you keep your setup simple and are less likely to run into compatibility issues and your system will consume less energy.

If the signal is transmitted digitally, your 5.1 system will handle the digital-analog conversion which means that the sound quality will almost exclusively depend on your 5.1 system and not on the sound card.

The arguments for leaving the card in would be if you connect the 5.1 system via an analog connection and the sound quality is better there, or if you play games that support better sound effects with the extra card.